# List All Oracle Database 12c Privileges

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

Where Can I Get All Privileges (System Privileges) Of Oracle Database?

I tried to list them from the oracle database 12c it self using select distanct query from the following tables:-

ALL_WORKSPACE_PRIVS

ALL_XS_IMPLIED_PRIVILEGES

CDB_RSRC_MANAGER_SYSTEM_PRIVS

CDB_SYS_PRIVS

CDB_WM_SYS_PRIVS

CDB_WORKSPACE_PRIVS

CDB_XS_IMPLIED_PRIVILEGES

DBA_RSRC_MANAGER_SYSTEM_PRIVS

DBA_SYS_PRIVS

DBA_XS_ACES

DBA_XS_IMPLIED_PRIVILEGES

ROLE_SYS_PRIVS

SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP

USER_SYS_PRIVS

USER_WM_PRIVS

USER_XS_ACES

USER_PRIVILEGE_MAP

TABLE_PRIVILEGE_MAP

The query list the privilegs, but is this all privileges that exist in oracle 12c ? and if not how can i get all the privileges ? is it available in oracle docs because i did not see them except a fewer than what i get from the system.

I prefer if the (System Privileges) list from the manual, but not this [Oracle Privilegs From Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3) because it does not contain all (System Privileges).

For examples the following privilegs does not exist on the above link:-

ACCESS_WORKSPACE

CREATE_WORKSPACE

ADMIN_SEC_POLICY

ADMINISTER_SESSION

ADMIN_NAMESPACE

MODIFY_SESSION

CREATE_SESSION

MODIFY_NAMESPACE

TERMINATE_SESSION

MODIFY_ATTRIBUTE

ATTACH_SESSION

ASSIGN_USER

Please Your Advice Is Highly Appreciated And Very Important.

Comment: If you're using Oracle 12c why do you reference the 11g documentation? The 12c reference lists both [object privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3) and [system privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3). Why do you think those are not complete?

Comment: I updated the link right now, it is the same as can i see
thanks for the notice

Comment: @APC Because I extract privilegs more than this from the oracle database installed on my machine. and i updated the question with example about the differences.

Comment: Those aren't normal privileges. They are [Real Application Security security classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbfsg/predefined-objects-in-real-application-security.html#GUID-D0BDAD25-C19F-471A-8237-AEEAD4252187) which are administered using XS_ADMIN_UTIL.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE procedure rather than a SQL  GRANT statement. RAS is a licensed product, a chargeable extra on the EE license.

Comment: ooooh yes i searched for Real Application Security security but did not now that, Is there is any pleace that have all this privileges in one pleace, becuase i searched for CDB and i think the container database also have 
another privileges that Its own and specially for CDB.